# Scrolling is flickering when routing to new page in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am experiencing a weird behaviour in my **Angular 13** + **Bootstrap 5** App.
On small screen size devices, when I visit a page that is supposed to scroll, the scrolling is not working at all and the page start flickering.

I've noticed that this problem is not happening when I force the page to refresh.

I've made nothing too complicated and my css is still almost clean.

The only thing I'm doing is use the `scrollPositionRestoration` to `top` in the `app-routing.module` like this:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'top' })
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here some code:

**header.html**

```html
<div class="container sticky-top bg-white">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <ws-navigation-bar></ws-navigation-bar>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**container-template.html**

```html
<ws-header></ws-header>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<ws-footer></ws-footer>
```

**blog-page.html**

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <wc-lib-page-title [pageTitle]="pageTitle"></wc-lib-page-title>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <wc-lib-spinner [isLoading]="isLoading"></wc-lib-spinner>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">

    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">

        <div class="row" *ngIf="blogPostItems.length===0 && isLoading===false">
            <div class="col-12">
                <p>No post yet!</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div *ngFor="let post of blogPostItems; index as i; trackBy: identifyItem">
                    <ws-post-card [id]="post.id" [postTitle]="post.title" [author]="post.author.displayName"
                        [published]="post.published" [content]="post.content" [replies]="post.replies.totalItems">
                    </ws-post-card>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Fon now, no other CSS classes have been used other than Bootstrap.

I've also tried without the `scrollPositionRestoration` behaviour but nothing is changed.

This issue is reproducible on all the browser I've tested: Safari, Chrome, Firefox.

The issue can be reproduced cloning, building and serving [this](https://github.com/iamlordsandro/angular-play) repo.

Could someone please suggest?
Thanks!

[image: scrolling-bug.gif]
[image: scrolling-bug-no-header]

Answer (score 1):

Sticky Headers are known to cause that issue.

Try adding to your header in your css

```
{
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Here are some good articles that may help you https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Using2Dand3DTransforms/Using2Dand3DTransforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008032-CH15-SW40.

https://www.angularfix.com/2021/10/header-shrinks-on-scroll-but-flickering.html

Comment: Unfortunately the issue seems not related to the sticky header.
I've made a tentative excluding at all the header but the issue is still reproducible.
I've also updated my question with a new .gif without header component.

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using. 

For setting the scrollbar you could do <div class="overflow-auto">...</div> 

how are you setting your overflow can you show your  layout . you can omit anything private. Or make a quick mockup.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap v5.1.3.
Before your comment I did not specify any overflow class.
I've updated my original post including some code.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me in recent days with a similar issue

```
html {
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not worked for me.